# problem with bluej error: int cannot be converted into int[]

Tags: java

I am trying to draw a triangle and I don't know how to get past this error.

this is the code within the class that has the error

```
g2d.fillPolygon(400, 400, 3);
```

it gives this error when I try to compile:

> Incompatible types: int cannot be converted into int[]

Can anyone help me??

Comment: Why do you believe a [polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon) can be defined by only a single point (400, 400)? --- What do you believe the third parameter (3) means, and why do you believe so?

Answer (score 0):

Java parses datatypes in the following ways.

```
"abc" - String
'a' - char
1 - int
1. - double
1.f - float
true - boolean
foo - variable
{1} - array of the type that's contained in it.
```

Your issue isn't the number of points in your parameter but the type that you used. If you aren't going to define an array explicitly and use it, like `int[] arr = new int[3]`, you are entering data straightforward and it's going to be parsed like that -  so to match the correct type for your parameter (int array), you need to surround it with brackets { } even for an array with a single element